# why is $f(x)=\sin \sqrt\frac{\cos^2 x - \cos x}{x}$ continuous at x=0?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Why is the function $\sin \sqrt\frac {\cos^2 x - \cos x}{x}$ continuous at $x=0$ even though  $\sin (\frac{\cos^2 x - \cos x}{x})$ is discontinuous at $x=0$?

Comment: Hi. Please take some time to write your question properly using $LaTeX$. Your function is :

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\cos^2x - \cos x})}{x} $$ ?

Comment: You are not asking the same question in the title and in the body.

Comment: My function is 
$f(x)=\sin \sqrt\frac{\cos^2 x - \cos x}{x}$.

However, I meant why the function with the square root is continuous even though the function without the square root is discontinuous, because I thought the square root did not matter when I substitute x=0 into both functions.

Comment: Neither of these are continuous at $x=0$. Explanation on my answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean :

$$f(x)=\sin \sqrt\frac{\cos^2 x - \cos x}{x} $$

then $f$ is obviously **not continuous** at $x=0$, as $D_f = \{x\in\mathbb R : \cos x(\cos x -1)\frac{1}{x} \geq 0 | x \neq 0\}.$

Same with :

$$g(x) = \sin\bigg(\frac{\cos^2x - \cos x}{x}\bigg) $$

as it is **not continuous** at $x=0$ , as $D_g = \{x\in\mathbb R : x \neq 0\}.$

By the way, you should mention that an one variable function is continuous at a point such as $x=x_0$. Being continuous at $(0,0)$ doesn't make much sense, since it's not a $2$-variable function.

Comment: Yes, I will keep that in mind. However, this question comes from a book and the answer says that it is continuous at the point mentioned. I was skeptical at first and graphed both functions (with and without the square root) on Desmos, but when I moused over the point x=0, the function without the square root shows (0,undefined) and the function with the square root shows (0,0), implying that it is continuous. I was confused by this.

Comment: None of these functions are defined at $x=0$, so it cannot be continuous there. Showing $(0,0)$ means that that point has values of $x=0,y=0$. This, though, should be the limit of the function. Continuity is also mentioned at the defined variable of the function, which is $x$. The variable $y$ is the value of the function at any $x$, $y=f(x)$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

i will write only the radicand: $$\cos(x)(\cos(x)-1)=\frac{\cos(x)(\cos(x)^2-1)}{\cos(x)+1}=\frac{-\cos(x)\sin(x)^2}{\cos(x)+1}$$ and then we get
$$\sqrt{\frac{-\cos(x)\sin(x)^2}{(\cos(x)+1)x^2}}$$
and use that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$

Comment: Neither of the functions given are continuous though for simple reasons.

Comment: Neither of the functions given is **defined** at x= 0 so cannot be continuous there.  The discontinuity might, however, be "removable".  If the limit, as x goes to 0, exists, then defining the value at x= 0 to be that limit "removes" the discontinuity.

Comment: Yes, I will keep that in mind.

However, this question comes from a book and the answer says that it is continuous at the point mentioned. I was skeptical at first and graphed both functions (with and without the square root) on Desmos, but when I moused over the point x=0, the function without the square root shows (0,undefined) and the function with the square root shows (0,0), implying that it is continuous. I was confused by this.